# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 1^-} \, e^{\frac{3}{1-x}}$?

Tags: limits

What steps are needed to evaluate the following?

$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \, e^{\frac{3}{1-x}}$

I know that the answer is $\infty$ but I don't know how to get there.

Thanks

P.S. I want to learn how to fish and not be given the fish so any generalized tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $u=\frac{3}{1-x}$ yields that $$\lim_{x\to 1} \, e^{\frac{3}{1-x}} = \lim_{u\to\infty}e^u = \infty$$ since if you let $x\to1$ in the expression for $u$, then $u$ will approach $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
Y=\lim_{x\to 1^-} \, e^{\frac{3}{1-x}}
$$

$$
ln(Y)=\lim_{x\to 1^-} \, {\frac{3}{1-x}} ln(e)=\lim_{x\to 1^-} \, {\frac{3}{1-x}}
$$

Comment: Aren't you then left with

$$
ln(Y)=\lim_{x\to 1^-} \, {\frac{3}{1-x}}
$$

instead of 

$$
Y=\lim_{x\to 1^-} \, {\frac{3}{1-x}}
$$

Comment: yeah that's what I wrote in my answer, not sure if its the best method but you are showing that since $ln(Y)=\infty$ then that should imply that what you were initially trying to solve is also $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Show you that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $X < 1$ such that if $x \leq X$ then
$$e^{\frac{3}{1-x}} > \varepsilon.$$
To see this, note that 
$$x \leq X \Rightarrow e^{\frac{3}{1-x}} > \varepsilon$$
is equivalent to
$$e^{\frac{3}{1-x}} \geq e^{\frac{3}{1-X}} > \varepsilon,$$
so that the choice
$$X := 1 - \frac{3}{\log 2\varepsilon}$$
suffices.

Comment: Sorry but you've completely lost me.

Comment: @GaryWhite: Oh just wanted to convince you that why the given function is divergent as $x$ goes to 1 from the left :)

Comment: @GaryWhite: Another "intuitive" way to see the divergence may be: Let $\delta := 1-x$. Then, since $x < 1$, we have $ \delta > 0$ so that $$e^{\frac{3}{1-x}} = e^{\frac{3}{\delta}}$$ and hence, as $\delta \to 0$ we have $$e^{\frac{3}{\delta}} \to \infty.$$